# Get x,y of image in Imageview onClick() with scale type fitCenter

Tags: android, android-imageview, touch-event

I have an ImageView, by using image resolution I have placed canvas objects on top of that Image

when I touched the ImageView it should return x,y of image not Imageview.
I don't want use FitXY scale type

currently I am getting x,y of Imageview

```
iv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        float x =  (event.getX())/2; // or getRawX();
                        float y =  (event.getY())/2;
                        System.out.println("drawn bounds:cx: "+x+"cy: "+y);
    return false;
            }
        });
```

Please help me to get x,y of image rather than Imageview.

Comment: what is your parent layout on this screen?

Comment: RelativeLayout @Java coder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this to get XY of image**

```
float bitmapWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
float bitmapHeight = bitmap.getHeight();    

float imageWidth = iv.getWidth();
float imageHeight = iv.getHeight();

float proportionateWidth = bitmapWidth / imageWidth;
float proportionateHeight = bitmapHeight / imageHeight;

int tapX = (int) (event.getX() * proportionateWidth);
int tapY = (int) (event.getY() * proportionateHeight);
```

Hope its help!